# which one is more right to say?

Tags: preposition, grammaticality

**Volkshochschule ist kostenlos, und jemand darin studieren kann.**

**Volkshochschule ist kostenlos, und jemand da studieren kann.**

Comment: The "kann" is placed at the wrong position. The Question should be if it is either "Volkshochschule ist kostenlos, und jemand kann darin studieren" or "Volkshochschule ist kostenlos, und jemand kann da studieren". In either case you would also add "Die" to the beginning of ech sentence.

Comment: To get this reopened please add an actual question and think of a better title. At present we can chose between two examples where the only correct answer would be **none**. This however will not help you much on any specific issue you may have, and more importantly it will not help any future visitor. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das sind keine Sätze.

"Die Volkshochschule ist kostenlos" wäre ein gültiger Anfang. Die Kombination **", und"** ist sehr selten richtig. Statt *jemand* müsste *man* stehen, denn *jemand* bezeichnet einen einzelnen Anonymus, etwa "Jemand hat das Marzipanbrot aufgegessen".

Außerdem gehört das *kann* vorgezogen.

"Die VHS ist kostenlos und man kann da/darin studieren." wäre ein richtiger Satz, wobei der fragliche Punkt noch zu klären ist.

Mit "da" ist es auch ein richtiger Satz. Dort ist da nicht besser. :)

Das *darin* jedoch fokussiert auf die Räumlichkeit, das Gebäude.

> Hier links sehen Sie die Volkshochschule. Deren Besuch ist kostenlos.
>   Man kann darin studieren.

Das wäre auch möglich.

Comment: Wie du schon andeutest: "Die Volkshochschule" ist nicht kostenlos. Ihr Betrieb kostet Geld. Kostenlos können allerdings einige ihrer Angebote sein. "Studieren" kann man darin aber nur, wenn man das Wort "studieren" so verwendet, als wäre es das Gleiche wie "to study". Neubürger aufgepasst! "Studieren" kann man in deutschsprachigen Raum bei korrektem Sprachgebrauch nur an Universitäten und Fachhochschulen (= tertiäre Bildung). "Volkshochschulen" heißen nur so, sind aber keine "Hochschulen" in diesem Sinne, sondern typische Einrichtungen der Erwachsenenbildung.

Comment: Ich kann auch die Sonderangebote im Katalog studieren. Ob die Aussage zu den Kosten der VHS der Wahrheit entsrpechen ist hier auch nicht das Thema. Es ist aber üblicher Sprachgebrauch "das Konzert ist kostenlos" zu sagen, wenn aus dem Kontext klar ist, dass es um die Börse des Besuchers, nicht des Veranstalters geht.

Comment: Ja, "das Konzert ist kostenlos" ist allgemein akzeptiert, das sehe ich auch so. Der Unterschied ist, dass das Konzert dasjenige ist, was jemand direkt besucht, die Volkshochschule jedoch nicht; jemand besucht einen Volkshochschulkurs (und der kann nach üblichem Sprachgebrauch kostenlos sein) oder einen Vortrag (dito) und so weiter. "Die Volkshochschule ist kostenlos" ist einfach kein Satz, der in der deutschsprachigen Alltagspraxis irgendwo vorkommen würde. (Noch dazu ist er faktisch falsch, weil die allermeisten Angebote von Volkshochschulen kostenpflichtig sind.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Doch, man besucht die Oper, die Volkshochschule, die Uni, das Stadion und das alles kann auch mal kostenlos sein. Bis auf den Studentenwerksbeitrag war die Uni zu meiner Zeit kostenlos. Kein formal elaborierter Sprachgebrauch, aber ich meine so redet man, nur nicht im Haushaltsausschuß, wo man die Kosten der anderen Seite im Blick hat.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing more right as both is completely wrong :-)

I would say "jemand kann **dort** studieren". This is most common.
"**Da** studieren" is ok, one can study **there**. But it is not so formal as "dort".
But "**darin** studieren" means to study **inside of it** which is a strange expression.

To the actual phrase, I am not even sure what exactly you want to express with it. "Volkshochschule is kostenlos" already implies a for-free course at Volkshochschule. (Often they are not free by the way).

So to make a better phrase you could say
**Volkshochschule ist kostenlos, man kann dort umsonst studieren.**
I am not sure if "studieren" (study) is the right verb to describe participating in a Volkshochschule class.